# how to pass multiple files and a json object in single post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I struggled for two days but not quite solution I found. Here is the scenario:

I have .NET MVC project and in current view user can add multiple rows by clicking "Add new Row". Each row contains 4 input type="text" and 1 input type="file". it is working absolutely fine.

Problem is happening when I post this form to my MVC controller. I am receiving all data at my MVC controller except Files that are uploaded in each row. This is how I am doing it.

View:

```html
<div class="row p-t-20">
 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Transaction Date</label>
 <input type="text" name="TransactionDate1" id="mdate1" class="form-control tdate01" value="" required />
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Description</label>
<textarea name="Description1" id="Description1" class="form-control descr01" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-1">
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="Amount1" id="Amount1" class="form-control amt01" required />
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-1">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Invoice #</label>
 <input type="text" name="InvoiceNo1" id="InvoiceNo1" class="form-control inv01" required />
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Comments</label>
<textarea name="Comments1" id="Comments1" class="form-control comm01" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Upload Invoice</label>
<input type="file" name="postedFile1"  id="postedFile1" class="form-control file01" required />
 <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfile1" id="hiddenfile1" value=""/>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
 <br />
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+ Row" class="btn btn-dark" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-actions m-t-40">
 **<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>**
</div>
```

jQuery Code

```js
var rowCount; var transactionDetailVM = []; var ClaimTransactionVM = {}; var reimFiles = []; var fileString = ''; var reader;
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    rowCount = 1;
    $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () { //
       // var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
        //Generating base64 string for previously uploaded file.
        //var filelogoUpload = $('#postedFile' + rowCount).get(0);
        //var files = filelogoUpload.files;
        //var file = files[0]; getBase64(file, rowCount);
        rowCount++;
        //Validations will run before adding a new row.
        var rowdiv = '<div class="row p-t-20">'         
           + '<div class="col-md-2">              '
            + ' <div class="form-group">          '
            + '  <label class="control-label">Transaction Date</label>'
            + ' <input type="text" name="TransactionDate' + rowCount + '" id="mdate' + rowCount +'" class="form-control tdate01" value="" required />'
            + '  </div>'
            + ' </div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2" >'
            + ' <div class="form-group">'
            + ' <label class="control-label">Description</label>'
            + '<textarea name="Description' + rowCount +'" id="Description' + rowCount +'" class="form-control descr01" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'                       
            + '<div class="col-md-1">'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label class="control-label">Amount</label>'
            + ' <input type="text" name="Amount' + rowCount + '" id="Amount' + rowCount +'" class="form-control amt01" />'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-1" >'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label class="control-label">Invoice #</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="InvoiceNo' + rowCount + '" id="InvoiceNo' + rowCount +'" class="form-control inv01" />'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2" >'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label class="control-label">Comments</label>'
            + '<textarea name="Comments' + rowCount +'" id="Comments' + rowCount +'" class="form-control comm01" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>'
            + ' </div></div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2">'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + ' <label>Upload Invoice</label>'
            + '<input type="file" name="postedFile' + rowCount + '" id="postedFile' + rowCount + '" class="form-control file01" />'
            //+ '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfile' + rowCount + '" id="hiddenfile' + rowCount+'"/>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2">'
              +'<div class="form-group">'
            + '<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+ Row" class="btn btn-dark" />'
            + '<input type = "button" id ="btnRemove" value="- Row" class="btn btn-danger" />'
              +'</div>'
              +'</div>'
              +'</div>';
        $('#newClaimForm').append(rowdiv);
        debugger;
       
        //$("input[name*='TransactionDate']").css("background-color", "yellow");
        // Adding these controls to Main table class
    });
});  

$(document).on("click", "#btnRemove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div[class='row p-t-20']").remove();
});

function getAllData() {
    console.log('getalldata called');
    var claimTitle = $('#TransactionName').val();
    var claimType = $('#ClaimTypes').val();
    //Transaction Details
    for (var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        //file operation
        var filelogoUpload = $('#postedFile' + i).get(0);
        var files = filelogoUpload.files;
        var file = files[0]; //getBase64(file);
        //reader = new FileReader();
        //reader.onload = function () {
        //    //console.log(reader.result);
        //    fileString = reader.result;
        //};
        //reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        //end file operation
        var trandate = $('#mdate' + i).val();
        var descr = $('#Description' + i).val();
        var amt = $('#Amount' + i).val();
        var invno = $('#InvoiceNo'+i).val();
        var comm = $('#Comments' + i).val();
        //var baseFileString = $('#hiddenFile' + i).val();
       
        debugger;
        
        console.log(trandate);
        console.log(descr);
        console.log(amt);
        console.log(invno);
        console.log(comm);
        console.log(file);
       

        
        var transactionDetails = {
            TransactionDate: trandate,
            Description: descr,
            Amount: amt,
            InvoiceNumber: invno,
            Comments: comm,
            baseFile: file
        }
        //console.log('Transaction Object:' + transactionDetails);
         //filled transaction Detail array
        transactionDetailVM.push(transactionDetails);
        console.log(transactionDetailVM);
        //reimFiles.push(file);
    }
        //filled model
        ClaimTransactionVM = {
            TransactionName: claimTitle,
            ClaimType: claimType,
            TransactionDetails: transactionDetailVM
        };
        //  console.log('Model:'+ClaimTransactionVM);
    }


$("#btnSubmit").click(function SaveReimbursements() {
    //Validations will run
    console.log('Save button called');
    debugger;
    getAllData();
    if (ClaimTransactionVM !== null) {
        var FormClaims = new FormData();
        FormClaims.append('currentClaim', JSON.stringify(ClaimTransactionVM));
        //FormClaims.append()
        //console.log(ClaimTransactionVM);
        //var data = {
        //    currentClaim: ClaimTransactionVM, 
        //    files: reimFiles
        //}
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ClaimProcess/CreateClaim',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: FormClaims,//JSON.stringify(ClaimTransactionVM),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === true) {
                    console.log('Success: IsSuccess True called');
                    swal({
                        title: 'success',
                        text: "Claim Added Successfully.",
                        type: "success",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#007AFF"
                    });
                }
                else if (response === false) {
                    console.log('Success: IsSuccess False called');
                    swal({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: '',
                        type: "warning",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Ok"
                    });
                }

            }
        });
       
    }
    else
        console.log('Model is empty.')

});
```

my final JSON object which needs to be passed is 'ClaimTransactionVM' which carries LIST of transaction details (each row that is added dynamically) and some other parameters.

I have tried following things already:

1. Used var reader = new FileReader(); and convert the file into base64 string and pass it in Json object. it works great in debug mode but in real-time reader.result doesn't get passed. no idea why. tried almost everything like recurring function to add delay to asynchronous code till my object gets filled. but no go.
2. Form data: used JSON.stringify to convertt the final Json object, it does pass but File doesn't get converted to HTTPPostedFileBase object. it skips the file while other params are received.

I would like to know how to send multiple Files and this JSON object together in my POST call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code, fixed some errors noticed and also fixed the upload, it uploads a base64 string now. At your .NET MVC, you change handle the base64 string and save it as a file.

Updated Code:

```js
var rowCount; var transactionDetailVM = []; var ClaimTransactionVM = {}; var reimFiles = []; var fileString = ''; var reader; var preview = '';
$(document).ready(function () {
    rowCount = 1;
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () { //
        rowCount++;
        //Validations will run before adding a new row.
        var rowdiv = '<div class="row p-t-20">'         
           + '<div class="col-md-2">              '
            + ' <div class="form-group">          '
            + '  <label class="control-label">Transaction Date</label>'
            + ' <input type="text" name="TransactionDate' + rowCount + '" id="mdate' + rowCount +'" class="form-control tdate01" value="" required />'
            + '  </div>'
            + ' </div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2" >'
            + ' <div class="form-group">'
            + ' <label class="control-label">Description</label>'
            + '<textarea name="Description' + rowCount +'" id="Description' + rowCount +'" class="form-control descr01" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'                       
            + '<div class="col-md-1">'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label class="control-label">Amount</label>'
            + ' <input type="text" name="Amount' + rowCount + '" id="Amount' + rowCount +'" class="form-control amt01" />'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-1" >'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label class="control-label">Invoice #</label>'
            + '<input type="text" name="InvoiceNo' + rowCount + '" id="InvoiceNo' + rowCount +'" class="form-control inv01" />'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2" >'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<label class="control-label">Comments</label>'
            + '<textarea name="Comments' + rowCount +'" id="Comments' + rowCount +'" class="form-control comm01" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>'
            + ' </div></div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2">'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + ' <label>Upload Invoice</label>'
            + '<input type="file" onChange="startRead2(\'' + rowCount + '\')" name="postedFile' + rowCount + '" id="postedFile' + rowCount + '" class="form-control file01" />'
            + '<input type="hidden" name="hiddenfile' + rowCount + '" id="hiddenfile' + rowCount+'"/>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="col-md-2">'
              +'<div class="form-group">'
            + '<input type = "button" id ="btnRemove" value="- Row" class="btn btn-danger" />'
              +'</div>'
              +'</div>'
              +'</div>';
        $('#newClaimForm').append(rowdiv);
        // debugger;
       
        //$("input[name*='TransactionDate']").css("background-color", "yellow");
        // Adding these controls to Main table class
    });
});  

$(document).on("click", "#btnRemove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div[class='row p-t-20']").remove();
});

function startRead2(id) {
       var file2 = document.getElementById('postedFile'+id);
       preview = id;

       if (!file2.files[0]) {
          return;
       }
       
       //add data type for upload validation
       if ((file2.files[0].type != 'image/jpeg') && (file2.files[0].type != 'image/jpg') && (file2.files[0].type != 'image/png')) {
          alert('File Type not Supported. File must be jpeg or png');
          file2.value = '';
          return;
       }

       let filex = file2.files[0];
       var reader2 = new FileReader();
       var reader_data2 = reader2.readAsDataURL(filex);
       reader2.onload = this.addImage2;
}

function addImage2(imgsrcs) {
       let hidden_bin = document.getElementById('hiddenfile'+preview);
       hidden_bin.value = imgsrcs.target.result;
}

function getAllData() {
    console.log('getalldata called');
    var claimTitle = $('#TransactionName').val();
    var claimType = $('#ClaimTypes').val();
    //Transaction Details
    for (var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        var trandate = $('#mdate' + i).val();
        var descr = $('#Description' + i).val();
        var amt = $('#Amount' + i).val();
        var invno = $('#InvoiceNo'+i).val();
        var comm = $('#Comments' + i).val();

        var transactionDetails = {
            TransactionDate: trandate,
            Description: descr,
            Amount: amt,
            InvoiceNumber: invno,
            Comments: comm,
            baseFile: base64_file
        }

        transactionDetailVM.push(transactionDetails);
        console.log(transactionDetailVM);
    }
        //filled model
        ClaimTransactionVM = {
            TransactionName: claimTitle,
            ClaimType: claimType,
            TransactionDetails: transactionDetailVM
        };

    }


$("#btnSubmit").click(function SaveReimbursements() {
    //Validations will run
    console.log('Save button called');
    // debugger;
    getAllData();
    if (ClaimTransactionVM !== null) {
        var FormClaims = new FormData();
        FormClaims.append('currentClaim', JSON.stringify(ClaimTransactionVM));


        $.ajax({
            url: '/ClaimProcess/CreateClaim',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: FormClaims,//JSON.stringify(ClaimTransactionVM),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === true) {
                    console.log('Success: IsSuccess True called');
                    swal({
                        title: 'success',
                        text: "Claim Added Successfully.",
                        type: "success",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#007AFF"
                    });
                }
                else if (response === false) {
                    console.log('Success: IsSuccess False called');
                    swal({
                        title: "Error!",
                        text: '',
                        type: "warning",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Ok"
                    });
                }

            }
        });
       
    }
    else
        console.log('Model is empty.')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row p-t-20">
 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Transaction Date</label>
 <input type="text" name="TransactionDate1" id="mdate1" class="form-control tdate01" value="" required />
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Description</label>
<textarea name="Description1" id="Description1" class="form-control descr01" cols="2" rows="2"></textarea>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-1">
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="Amount1" id="Amount1" class="form-control amt01" required />
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-1">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Invoice #</label>
 <input type="text" name="InvoiceNo1" id="InvoiceNo1" class="form-control inv01" required />
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Comments</label>
<textarea name="Comments1" id="Comments1" class="form-control comm01" cols="1" rows="2"></textarea>
 </div>
</div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Upload Invoice</label>
<input type="file" name="postedFile1" onChange="startRead2('1')"  id="postedFile1" class="form-control file01" required />
 <input type="hidden" name="hiddenfile1" id="hiddenfile1" value=""/>
</div>
</div>
 

 <div id="newClaimForm"></div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
 <br />
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+ Row" class="btn btn-dark" />
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-actions m-t-40">
 **<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>**
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. It was a good idea to bind it on 'OnChange' Event. Thank you so much for your time on this.

One strange thing I noticed that when I used jQuery to read the base64 value of hidden field, it is unable to do it. But when I used plain javascript it worked.

jQuery: $('#hiddenFile' + i).val(); //doesnt not work.

Javascript: document.getElementById('hiddenfile' + i).value //does work

No idea why is that.

Comment: Glad it worked. What you noticed about jQuery is strange, but to be on the safe side, just stick to pure JavaScript on simple task, like collecting data value and stuff.